# Python: How to code the Hi_1 (previous line) (Hi+Hi_1)*qi

Tags: python, pandas

---

Dear all,

I have a question which would be quiet simple to do in Excel, but I fail so in Python.

The following formular needs to be calculated: (Hi+Hi_1)*qi

[Table screenshot with the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOlAA.png)

How can I do the coding to pick Hi and qi from the same line, however, Hi_1 from the previous line.

```
df1['gini_coef'] = (df['Hi'] + '???') * df['qi']
```

Any help and suggestions are most appreciated.

Kind regards
Sina

Comment: For the future, this is not a Python question, this is a pandas question.  I added the tag.  In many cases, the easiest way to do this is to add another column that contains your first column rotated down by one row.  Now you can do the subtraction easily.

Comment: Thanks Tim, did not know that I need to tag particular packages. But will do so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number index on your dataframe you can use from a simple row and iterate on your dataframe. For itrating on your dataframe there are many ways. A simple way is :

(If you index is not integer you can use from reset_index

```py
df ['newcol'] = 0
For i in range(1,df.index):
    df['newcol'][i] = (df['Hi'][i] + df[Hi_1][i-1]) * df['qi'][i]
```

Comment: Many thanks Ali, looks good. I thought of sth. like a loop.

Comment: Ok I hopefull this is usefull for you